# Polymorphic select query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, orm, mapping

There are following tables:

```
message_table = Table(
    "message",
    metadata,
    # attributes
    Column("message_id", INTEGER, primary_key=True),
    Column("chat_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
    Column("content", VARCHAR, nullable=False),
    Column("created_at", INTEGER, nullable=False),
    Column("reply_to", INTEGER, nullable=True),
    Column("is_deleted", BOOLEAN, nullable=False, default=False),
    # relations
    ForeignKeyConstraint(["chat_id"], ["chat.chat_id"]),
)

user_message_table = Table(
    "user_message",
    metadata,
    # attributes
    Column("message_id", INTEGER, primary_key=True),
    Column("chat_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
    Column("maker_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False),
    # relations
    ForeignKeyConstraint(["maker_id"], ["user.user_id"]),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(
        ["chat_id", "message_id"], ["message.chat_id", "message.message_id"]
    ),
)

bot_message_table = Table(
    "bot_message",
    metadata,
    # attributes
    Column("message_id", INTEGER, primary_key=True),
    Column("chat_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
    Column(
        "importance",
        ENUM(model.MessageImportance, name="message_importance"),
        nullable=False,
    ),
    Column("chatbot_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False),
    # relations
    ForeignKeyConstraint(
        ["chat_id", "message_id"], ["sh_message.chat_id", "sh_message.message_id"]
    ),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(["chatbot_id"], ["chatbot.chatbot_id"]),
)
```

There are corresponding business model objects for them:

```
@dataclass
class Message(BaseModel):
    message_id: Union[int, SetLatestAvailable]
    chat_id: UUID
    content: str
    created_at: int
    reply_to: Optional[int]


@dataclass
class UserMessage(Message):
    maker: User


@dataclass
class BotMessage(Message):
    importance: MessageImportance
    chatbot: ChatBot
```

And these objects are mapped with tables:

```
    message_mapper = mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        model.Message,
        message_table,
        polymorphic_identity="message",
        with_polymorphic="*"
    )
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        model.UserMessage,
        user_message_table,
        properties={"maker": relationship(user_mapper, lazy="subquery")},
        inherits=message_mapper,
        polymorphic_identity="user_message",
    )
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        model.BotMessage,
        bot_message_table,
        properties={"chatbot": relationship(chatbot_mapper, lazy="subquery")},
        inherits=message_mapper,
        polymorphic_identity="bot_message",
    )
```

The problem arises that when I want to perform a polymorphic select on table "message" (i.e., ultimately get one of its inherited objects), the parent object is still returned to me.
My query:

```
    def _get(self, message_id, chat_id):
        poly_select = with_polymorphic(model.Message, [model.BotMessage, model.UserMessage])
        stmt = select(poly_select).filter_by(message_id=message_id, chat_id=chat_id).filter_by(is_deleted=False)
        message = self.session.scalars(stmt).first()
        return message
```

I can't understand what is causing this behavior. The connection is indicated in the mappers. In the request I explicitly specify that I want to work with polymorphy.